# wice_grid icons not showing up on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wice-grid

I am using wice_grid to show list of questions on my website. Wice_grid comes up with bunch of icons for filtering, excel export etc. These icons show up on my development server, but they dont show up on heroku. I can click on the point where the icon should have been for example, filter icon and it lets me filter, but I cannot see the icon. Can someone please advice what I need to do to get the icons?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in wice_grid where the icons aren't properly set up for the asset pipeline.

There is a todo issue in github concerning this problem: https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/issues/128
For now, it seems like people are using the workaround of downloading a copy of the icons into their app/assets folder, and changing the css file to use asset-url and putting the calendar icon in the public folder.  See the link to the github issue for more details.  None of this is a pretty way to do it, so the gem should be updated, but at least as of 5/16/14, it hasn't been.

Answer (score 0):

In `/initializers/wice_grid_config.rb`, add this line to  `Wice::Defaults::CALENDAR_ICON`

```
# Icon to popup the calendar.
Wice::Defaults::CALENDAR_ICON = "https://raw.github.com/leikind/wice_grid/rails3/vendor/assets/images/icons/grid/calendar_view_month.png"
```